# How to call original method after its override

Tags: javascript

In **Javascript**, when I override `Date.prototype.toString` function, the output of the `Date()` function is not affected and the function keeps its original code.

```
console.log(Date());
console.log(new Date().toString());

Date.prototype.toString = function() { return this.toISOString() }

console.log(Date());
console.log(new Date().toString());
```

> "Tue Jan 26 2021 17:30:33 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
>
> "Tue Jan 26 2021 17:30:33 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
>
> "Tue Jan 26 2021 17:30:33 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
>
> "2021-01-26T22:30:33.821Z"

Test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/j4eqawvt/).

---

However, when I needed to use a more complex override of the `Date` class - in my case changing the clock step to 5-second interval - after I override `Date.prototype.toString` function, the output of the `Date()` changes as well. Since the functionality of the `Date()` function should not change, this is
an unwanted and unwelcome change.

```
console.log(Date());
console.log(new Date().toString());

(function() {
  let ___now = Date.now;
  Date = new Proxy(Date, {
    construct(target, args) {
      if (args[0] === undefined) args[0] = this.adjust()
      let date = new target(...args);
      return date;
    },
    apply(target, thisArg, argumentList) {
      return new Date(this.adjust()).toString();
    },
    adjust() {
      return 5000 * Math.floor(___now() / 5000);
    }
  });
})();
Date.prototype.toString = function() { return this.toISOString() }

console.log(Date());
console.log(new Date().toString());
```

> "Tue Jan 26 2021 17:30:35 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
>
> "Tue Jan 26 2021 17:30:35 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
>
> "2021-01-26T22:30:35.000Z" "2021-01-26T22:30:35.000Z"
>
> "2021-01-26T22:30:35.000Z" "2021-01-26T22:30:35.000Z"

Test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oeamkL50/).

---

How should I modify the code above to force `Date()` function to use the original `toString()` function, even when it is overridden? The change of `toString()` should be applicable only when it is called explicitly, as shown in the examples above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```js
console.log(Date());
console.log(new Date().toString());

(function() {
  const ___now = Date.now;
  const ___toString = Date.prototype.toString;
  Date = new Proxy(Date, {
    construct(target, args) {
      if (args[0] === undefined) args[0] = this.adjust()
      let date = new target(...args);
      return date;
    },
    apply(target, thisArg, argumentList) {
      return ___toString.bind(new Date()).call();
    },
    adjust() {
      return 5000 * Math.floor(___now() / 5000);
    }
  });
})();

Date.prototype.toString = function() { return this.toISOString() }

console.log(Date());
console.log(new Date().toString());
```